# Programmatically setting the borderbrush of a border within a datatemplate in a datagrid in a usercontrol

Tags: wpf, user-controls, datatemplate

I have a UserControl which is basically a DataGrid. The datagrid has one TemplateColumn which is bound to an object.

I want to add a property to the UserControl which will set the Borderbrush that is inside the DataTemplate.

Here is my Xaml:

```
 <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="No" IsReadOnly="True">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Border x:Name="ElementBorder" BorderThickness="1">
                                <Viewbox Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Top"></TextBlock>
                                </Viewbox>
                            </Border>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
```

I would like to set the ElementBorder's BorderBrush property based on a "ElementBorderColor" property in my UserControl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution... point your BorderBrush to a resource in your control and, in code, change the resource. Something like this:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="scb01"
                 Color="Red" />

<DataTemplate x:Key="dt01">
  <Border x:Name="ElementBorder"
          BorderThickness="1"
          BorderBrush="{DynamicResource scb01}">
    <Viewbox Height="Auto"
             VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                 VerticalAlignment="Top"></TextBlock>
    </Viewbox>
  </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

In code:

```
(Resources["scb01"] as SolidColorBrush).Color = Colors.Green;
```